# Write text with a button command and save the file tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a button with a command function. When I click the button, I would like the command (no_scatter) to be written into a plain text file that I can save to my harddrive. How do I do this? Everything I have tried only opens a blank window that I can type into, but not one that automatically fills with the no_scatter command results. The output would be a plain text file like the following example:

G20
G90
M3S200
G1X0.03125F20
G1X0.0625F15
G1X0.09375F10
G1X0.125F10S300
G1X0.15625F10
G1X0.1875F10
G1X0.21875F15
G1X0.25F20S600
G1X0.21875F20
G1X0.1875F15
G1X0.15625F10
G1X0.125F10S1200
G1X0.09375F10
G1X0.0625F10
G1X0.03125F15
G1X0.000F20

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os
os.system('clear')

root = Tk()
root.title('Test File')
root.geometry("400x1000")
root.configure(bg='light grey')

def no_scatter():
    blockone = 'G20' \
               'G90' \
               'M3S200' \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .125, 'F20', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .25, 'F15', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .375, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .5, 'F20S300', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .625, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .75, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .875, 'F15', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()), 'F20S600', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .875, 'F20', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .75, 'F15', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .625, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .5, 'F10S1200', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .375, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .25, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .125, 'F15', \
               'G1X.000F20'
    blocktwo = 'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .125, 'F20', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .25, 'F15', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .375, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .5, 'F20', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .625, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .75, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .875, 'F15', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()), 'F20', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .875, 'F20', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .75, 'F15', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .625, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .5, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .375, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .25, 'F10', \
               'G1X', float(e1.get()) * .125, 'F15', \
               'G1X.000F20'
    no_scatter = blockone, blocktwo * 100


myLabel = Label(root, text='Enter Core Height', bg='light grey')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)
e1 = Entry(root, width=10, justify='center', border=0)
e1.pack()

Button(root, text='No Scatter', command=no_scatter).pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is pretty basic, have you not looked for any tutorials on writing to a file.

Comment: It's unclear what format you want the data written to the file to be in. Please [edit] your question and show sample output. To write data to a file, you have to `open()` one,  call its `write()` method one or more times, and call its `close()` method when you're done. This is very basic stuff. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: The only tutorials I could find explain either how to open a blank window, which the user can type into, or how to open an existing document. That is not what I want. I want to click the button and automatically generate text, based on my no_scatter command. Then I would save it to my hard drive. If I could find a tutorial for this, I would be here.

Comment: At the end of the `no_scatter` fucntion add `with open("filename.txt", "w") as f:`, then a newline and a tab, then `f.write(no_scatter)`. I would advise naming the function and the string something different (as they are both currently `no_scatter`).